# In World of Warcraft, how can I find a merchant?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I can't seem to find a similar question on Arqade. Yesterday I managed to find a thread somewhere where one person said pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to bring the map up would give you the option to look for venders. However, for the life of me, I cannot find that same thread no matter how hard on google I try.

What I want to do is find a store in Stormwind where I can buy rogue armor and rogue weapons, but more so I want the ability to locate stores in general, not having to close the game and google it every time. How can I find a vender on World of Warcraft?

When I press <kbd>M</kbd>, it brinds up the map with any local quest I am doing on the right side. There is a drop down on the bottom right with one option, `Show Objectives`. Accross the top of the map there are dropdowns that let me select other maps. I don't see any kind of legend or filter. Is the ability to find venders on maps removed or unavailible to starter accounts?

here is a screen shot from when I press <kbd>M</kbd>:
[image: map of stormwind]

Comment: The gear you're going to be buying from vendors is garbage that you don't want anyway. The only vendors you should be concerned with early on are food/water merchants, crafting supplies, and repairs.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yeah, that's what I read elsewhere as well. However, I would still like the ability to find merchants. Also, I'm at the 10gold cap for starter accounts and would like something to buy. I want to compare my current armour, all from questing, to the shops to see if I can improve it any bit.

Comment: If your armor is green or better, you won't be able to improve it with gold at a vendor. Full Stop.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz How about finding shops for consumable items? Is there a way for me to locate them without having to run like a maniac through storm wind? I have gotten my game to run at a max of 11 fps (7 year old computer), however in the trade district of Stormwind, it runs from 0 to 2fps. I've found a store before but when returning to Stormwind was not able to locate it again, having spent half hour of searching through confusing streets.

Comment: Yeah, the filters exist for that in the dropdown -  I'm not posting an answer because I don't have an active WoW sub/install to take a screenshot for you. I'm sure someone who does will be along shortly though.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFixx thanx! that's promising and what I hoped for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Minimap has a small circular icon of a magnifying glass attached to it. Click it and you will get a list of the things that you can track on your Minimap. Just check the ones you want to look for in your map.

- Vendors that sell food and drinks are signified by a bread and milk icon.
- Vendors that sell reagents (for spells, etc) are signified by a
  reagent icon, which sort of looks like a rune-like thing.
- Vendors that sell armor or weapons usually can repair armor and weapons, and
  are signified by an anvil.
- Some innkeepers also have some stuff to sell, and they are signified by a hearthstone icon.

If you are in a capital city, you may talk to the guards and they can help you find what you're looking for. An arrow will show on your minimap and a red flag icon will show where you can find what you're looking for.

You may take a look at [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Minimap) for images and more information regarding your Minimap.